# How to get parent objects and nested children objects by parent and children ids

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a parent object (blogpost) and nested items (comments)
The parent and nested objects are both keyed by an id

So if I fetch the parent object, i will get all the children too

```
GET /my_index/blogpost/1
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "Nest eggs",
  "body":  "Making your money work...",
  "tags":  [ "cash", "shares" ],
  "comments": [ 
    {
      "id":    2,
      "comment": "Great article",
      "age":     28,
      "stars":   4,
      "date":    "2014-09-01"
    },
    {
      "id":    4,
      "comment": "More like this please",
      "age":     31,
      "stars":   5,
      "date":    "2014-10-22"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Question**

However, I only want to fetch the parent and a subset of children based on children ids

e.g. My desired behaviour is this:

```
GET /my_index/blogpost/1?onlyGetCommentIds=4
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "Nest eggs",
  "body":  "Making your money work...",
  "tags":  [ "cash", "shares" ],
  "comments": [ 
    {
      "id":    4,
      "comment": "More like this please",
      "age":     31,
      "stars":   5,
      "date":    "2014-10-22"
    }
  ]
}
```

See in the above example that only comment id == 4 is returned along with the parent object.

How do I construct this query?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [nested `inner_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html#nested-inner-hits) in order to achieve what you want

```
POST /my_index/blogpost/_search
{
  "_source": {
    "exclude": "comments"
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "id": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "comments",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "comments.id": 4
              }
            },
            "inner_hits": {}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The response will include the parent object (without the `comments` nested objects) and another `inner_hits` section containing only the desired nested comment with id = 4.